# Transaction in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am new to Spring and have a question about transactions.

I know that for each http request there is a servlet thread which has its own stack. As far I know all the local variables and method reside on the stack. So if I have a method `public void A();` then both the servlet thread A and thread B have a copy of a function in their stack.

Now If I annotated a method with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED ,timeout=1,isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)` then I would like to know the following points:

1. Does each thread A and thread B have their own stack and work independently?
2. If thread A is updating something and B is reading something because of in different stack is Isolation will work? or B will read the data with out any information about the thread A?

I want to know this by the diagram so that I can understand how end to end things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread has its own stack, you're right here. But they don't have copies of methods. Method is just a series of operations. But they have copies of variables inside this method (local variables).

Speaking about isolation level, actually it has nothing to do with threads and stacks. It refers to a **database isolation level** notion. Spring asks your database for that level to be used for database transaction.  PostreSQL has a great [doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) explaining transaction isolation.

So it's not quite right here to ask how threads see each other, because in the sense of data they see what they get from the database. And the database returns data accordingly to current transaction isolation level. Each thread starts its own transaction, i.e. it creates a new connection to the database and tells it to start a new transaction.

### Example

To feel what's going on under the hood, here is an example. Suppose you have such method:

```
@Transactional
public Person getPerson(int id) {
    Person person = em.find(Person.class, id);
    return person;
}
```

Here is what's going on under the Spring's hood per each line:

```
@Transactional
public Person getPerson(int id) {
// SQL sent to the database:
// Begin transaction

Person person = em.find(Person.class, id);
// SQL sent to the database:
// select p from person p where p.id = id
// the data from the database then gets converted to Java Person class

return person;
}
// after end of the method Spring automatically commits the transaction (not always, it depends on the `propagation` setting)
// SQL sent to the database:
// commit
```

Please, read PostgreSQL docs that explains transaction isolation in depth. Java threads only receive data accordingly to it.

Comment: "Spring asks your database for that level to be used for database transaction. " - Thanks for this important line :)

Comment: If i would have access to upvote your ans i would definately do ,your answer says everything i was searching on internet from last 10 days. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thread B will only see modifications in the database done by Thread A after the transaction of thread A completes.

It is still possible that thread B reads something from the database, then thread A updates something in the database and commits, and then thread B overwrites what thread A wrote.

To avoid that, you need to use some type of locking on the database, or use a stricter isolation level (but that carries high performance penalties, as often the database needs to perform a lot of locking to implement the stricter isolation level)

Comment: Great!! but to be more clear can you please tell me that how thread A and thread B are aware about each other transaction they are in the different stack right? I know I am asking silly things but for me its very helpful for foundation of concept.

Comment: @BeerGupta They will use different physical TCP connections to the database server.

Answer (score 0):

Brifely:

1. yes
2. B will read data with out any information about the thread A

Now Why this? in a servlet enviroment you have tipicaly one or more servlet and all dataat the class level and for this reason outside the doHttp methods share same data, servlet aren't thread safe.

But of course data inside a method are thread safe because each method callis a call function and will have a your thread for serving the method request and it has its own stack.

However if you have two concurrent method call and for this reason in two separated thread the the transaction will be not the same because the thrad local aren't the same and don't share the same immage of the db it is natural if you think about JPA the persistanceContext is a first level cache that is stored in the threadlocal. the my advice is use a higer level of transaction isolation for mitigate possible problem

I hope that it can help you